# Fixing local JSON file for working with structs

Tags: json, swift

I have a local json file like this

```
    {
      "scroll": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "titles": "1",
          "course": ["first", "Second"]
          
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "titles": "2",
          "course": ["Third", "Fourth"]
        }
]
}
```

So, I want that every item of "course" has its own string parameter. For example, "Third" has "third" parameter, "Fourth" has "fourth" parameter and so on. But I don't know how to do it in json file. I want that clicking "first" button in the list it navigate to the text that is written in json, and after clicking in "Second " button it navigate to another text. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "its own parameter", could you add an example? Are you talking about other keys or values or both?

Comment: For example, here "course" has its value that is array of string. How can the items of that array have also values? @JoakimDanielson

Comment: do you mean "course": [{"third": "value"},  {"fourth": "value"}] ??

Comment: I added a photo in my question, please can you look through it? @OscarFernandez

Comment: Make the value of "course" into a dictionary, `"course": {"first": "value", "second": "value"}`

Comment: if I make dictionaries I can't call that keys to get my list items. I receive struct Course: Codable {
    let first, sec, third, fourth: [String]?
    let fifth, sixth, seventh, eight: [String]?
    let ninth, ten: [String]?
} and here I don't know how to make list from this(

Comment: what about this? "course": [{"title": "first", "content": "my 1st text"}, {"title": "second", "content": "my 2nd text"}]

Comment: this also doesnt  work, I need separate "course" for each block @OscarFernandez

Comment: Sorry but your requirements are very hard to understand and right now this is a guessing game. Please improve your question and describe better both in code and words what your input and expected output is.

Comment: You should try to add a course struct with its contents : title, description, duration, … You can do as much struct as you want as long as you make these Codable for your json file. And think of what are your model objects : course, lesson… I do not see what « scroll » means, except if you try to make a view hierarchy that build automatically from json file without knowing anything about what are the object it shows.

Comment: So, after many tries, I found that your variants were true, thanks a lot for helping.) @OscarFernandez